# gData: get account(self contact) first and last name

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, gdata, accountmanager

I want to get first and last name of a google account using gdata library. I have the auth token(I take it from android device - send it to my java servlet- then should add an insert into a mysql db with first, last, display name and provider_uid(provider_uid is the form of https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawmyn...)).

I used Contacts feed like this(without success):

```
public String tryGoogleAuthentication(String auth_token){
    ContactsService contactsService = new ContactsService("...");
    contactsService.setUserToken(auth_token);
    //contactsService.setAuthSubToken(auth_token);

    ContactFeed feed = null;
    try {
        feed = contactsService.getFeed(new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/" + "someEmail@gmail.com" + "/full?max-results=10000"), ContactFeed.class);            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return CONST.GOOGLE_AUTH_INVALID_TOKEN;
    } catch (ServiceException e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();
        return CONST.GOOGLE_AUTH_INVALID_TOKEN;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return CONST.GOOGLE_AUTH_INVALID_TOKEN;
    }

    if (feed == null)
        return "";

    String externalId = feed.getId();
    Person person = feed.getAuthors().get(0);
    String email = person.getEmail();
    String name = person.getName();
    String nameLang = person.getNameLang();
    String extensionLocalName = person.getExtensionLocalName();
    String uri = person.getUri();



    System.out.println("externalId: " + externalId);
    System.out.println("email: " + email);
    System.out.println("name: " + name);
    System.out.println("nameLang: " + nameLang);
    System.out.println("extension local name: " + extensionLocalName);
    System.out.println("URI: " + uri);   
    System.out.println(feed.getSelf().getEntries().get(0).getTitle().getPlainText());   


    return CONST.STATUS_OK;
}
```

Also,

```
System.out.println("ID: "  + feed.getSelf().getEntries().get(0).getId());
```

will output:

```
ID: http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/someEmail%40gmail.com/base/c....
```

but I want something like this:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawmyn...
```

I need this to insert into an existing data base.

Please note that I want the info only for the account, not for it's contacts.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Still nobody knows how to get first and last name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/oauth2-dev/SMntRijLz5o) from google groups for resolution. The problem is that I cannot access user profile with the auth_token taken from the android because it's a Client Login token, and Client Login does not have a scope for accessing user's profile. I integrated OAUTH login in android like [this](http://nilvec.com/implementing-client-side-oauth-on-android/) and with the token returned, I can access user's profile.

Alex.