# Android: client secret key is missing for OAuth 2.0

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I am trying to upload videos to youtube using my Android application. But first of all, I must implement the OAuth authentication protocol. Luckily, I am able to access the *redirect_uri* and the auto generated *code*. Now, I want the exchange the authorization code for access tokens but for that I need to have the ***client_secret*** for making the POST request to the google server. Unlucky for me, there is no *client_secret* key in my google console account.

I have tried to download the JSON object from console but there isn't any *client_secret* key.

Comment: [Google APIs Console - missing client secret](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11295661)

Answer (score 0):

Android OAuth2 client doesn't have a client_secret since there is no way you can store a secret on client side securely. Instead, you should use [GoogleAuthUtil from google-play-services](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html) to get an access token for your Android app and use the toke to upload videos. [This blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/09/google-play-services-and-oauth-identity.html) explains more on how to get an access token on Android.

Comment: Thanks..I got the token by selecting the account. Now I want to access the YoutubeAPI and upload the video. Is there any library to call the Youtube API? It will save my time a lot..