# How to get client secret for iOS for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-storage

I am trying the [Google API Objective C Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client) and running the storage example.

I notice that the API requires both a client ID and client secrete to sign in and this is the [`GTMOAuth2Authentication`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/gtm-oauth2/0.0.1/Classes/GTMOAuth2Authentication.html#//api/name/authenticationWithServiceProvider:tokenURL:redirectURI:clientID:clientSecret:) function that is being called.

```
+ (id)authenticationWithServiceProvider:(NSString *)serviceProvider
               tokenURL:(NSURL *)tokenURL 
            redirectURI:(NSString *)redirectURI  
               clientID:(NSString *)clientID 
           clientSecret:(NSString *)clientSecret
```

I read about this question:

[How to get client secret from Google Developers Console in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071856/how-to-get-client-secret-from-google-developers-console-in-ios)

I tried it and can get a client secret with Web Application. Obviously that doesn't work. I got an error message as the following:

> The redirect URI in the request: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the 'WEB' client type. You can create a Client ID for native application in the Credentials section of the Google Developers Console.

But I don't understand how to get one client secret for iOS application. Anybody know how? Or is there a work around with this API?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [create credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential) to use from your app. Part of the credentials will be the Client ID.
Also, you may want to read about [using OAuth 2 to access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: Thanks, but the [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) is all bout the theory of OAuth 2. Do you know how to do it coding wise?