# How to obtain Client Secret in Youtube API for iOS client?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I'm working on iOS app that contains feature uploading video on Youtube.

I followed an example project from [yt-direct-lite-ios](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS). The project requires *client id* and *client secret*

I went to console.developers.google.com to create *client id* (with iOS client). However I can ONLY find the *client id*. So where can I obtain *client secret* from here?

I have also checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071856/how-to-get-client-secret-from-google-developers-console-in-ios) and still not work for me.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: that project is a little old isn't it?  I think things have changed it doesn't appear that Ios keys have client secret, or redirect URI.   I wonder if it would work with a browser key.

Comment: That project quite old, I agree. I will try with browser key and let you know.

Comment: @DaImTo - I tried to use 'client id' and 'client secret' from browser key and still not work. Do you have any suggestions for uploading video to youtube via iOS app? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a secret with the iOS client. (there used to be and that is why the example needs it but we have gotten rid of it). Just leave it blank and it should work.

Comment: It works! stupid me. just leave it blank. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to leave blank the secret Key, In this case You just select `OAuth 2.0 client ID` in `Add Credential`. It's Work successfully